# Get value correspondence to max value of another column in python

Tags: python

I want to know the related station code in column 'stasjon-kd' for both maximum and minimum  value of the column 'std-tid' which is grouped by tog-nr. I have written the code below. but it gives me error.

```
def stasjon_fra_to(path):
    stasjon_kd,std_tid = path
    np.where('std_tid' == arr.max(),'stasjon_kd',NA)

std_1['Stajon'] = std_1[['stasjon_kd','std_tid']].apply(stasjon_fra_to)
```

The error is :

```
NameError: ("global name 'arr' is not defined", u'occurred at index stasjon_kd')
```

Although I am not sure if the codes above will lead me to the right answer.

[sample of sorted data for train number 44](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1urcg.png)

Comment: Hi @Nakisa, welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you please post some sample data and the expected result?

Comment: yes, surely. I just added the photo of a sample data sorted by date and train number, this part of the  data is for one of the trains-number 44 out of many  passing many different stations.

Comment: Hi @Nakisa - welcome to Stack Overflow. I made some edits to make the code more readable. I don't think I completely understand the question but the error in the code seems to be that when you do `arr.max()` the variable `arr` is not defined. Is the intention to find the max value of the `std_tid` column?

Comment: Hi @Nakisa, please take a look at this thread where the best way to post an example dataset is discussed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples . When you post images, you are not helping others to reproduce the error you are receiving, and it reduces the chance of someone answer your question.